# When I convert string to int it shows The argument type 'String?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
int item = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
```

`"Error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't."`

I didn't know what this want to mean, I just want to convert a string that I will type into integer

I'm using VScode with Dart extension

Thanks for your attention

Comment: int item = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()) ?? 0;

Comment: because **stdin** is nullable

Comment: @A.Sang `stdin` it not nullable. `stdin.readLineSync` might return `null`.

Comment: yes simply typo. but using **?? 0** solved

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the null safety feature in Dart, see https://dart.dev/null-safety.

`int.Parse()` requires a non-null string. While `std.readLineSync()` is of a nullable string type.

If you check that the user gave input, you can confirm that the value is not null.

Something like:

```
if(item ==null){
    print("empty input not allowed");
}
else{
    int item = int.parse(stdin.ReadLineSync());
    print(item);
}
```

You can also use `tryParse` instead.

```
var itemInt = int.tryParse(item ?? "");
```

Comment: int.tryParse return **true** or **false**

Comment: ```var item = stdin.readLineSync();
if(item != null) {
  var item = int.parse(s);
}```
This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 int item = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()??"0");
```

instead of this

```
int item = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
```

[image]

here in the image you can see readLineSync return `String?` not `String`
so the chance of reading input string may be non string value or emptyline .so we cant convert to number.